# plist to tableview when root is array then dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, plist, tableview

I see example and tutorial after tutorial of how to load tableview from plist when root is dictionary but I have to use a plist that is an array. 
plist setup:

```
root  Array
   Item 0  Dictionary
         name String
   Item 1  Dictionary
         name String
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *thumbnails = [[NSArray alloc] init];

      for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData){

         NSLog(@"%@",dict); // prints all key value pairs in dictionary

         thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

      }
      NSLog(@"outside %@", thumbnails);  // this prints last value added to thumbnails array 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", thumbnails);  // this loads last value added to array thumbnails

    cell.textLabel.text = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I'm doing this wrong...it doesn't load into my tableview and crashes. I think my for loop is wrong and I think my objectAtIndex is wrong because it crashes at that line. I'm more than happy to share more information. I have datasource and delegate of tableview hooked up to file's owner. I've tested that the tableview works with loading an array directly into it. Please help, I appreciate it.

EDIT:

I placed declaration for the mutable array thumbnails at the top of my .m file as you see below:

```
@interface SimpleTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *thumbnails;
@end
```

These changes still unfortunately leave me with empty thumbnails array in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Same when @property is placed into .h file

EDIT: .m file (latest code)

```
#import "SimpleTableViewController.h" 

@interface SimpleTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SimpleTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   

   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"plist"];

   NSArray *tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
   NSMutableArray *thumbnails = [NSMutableArray array];

   for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData){
       NSLog(@"%@",dict); // prints all key value pairs in dictionary
      [thumbnails addObject:dict[@"name"]];
   }
       NSLog(@"outside %@", thumbnails);   

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

   return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSLog(@"other method%@", self.thumbnails);  // this loads last value added to array thumbnails
    cell.textLabel.text = self.thumbnails[indexPath.row];

    return cell;


}

@end
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *thumbnails;

@end
```

Comment: post the crash message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *thumbnails = [NSMutableArray array];

      for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData){
         NSLog(@"%@",dict); // prints all key value pairs in dictionary
         [thumbnails addObject:dict[@"name"];
      }
      NSLog(@"outside %@", thumbnails);  // this prints last value added to thumbnails array 
}
```

EDIT :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *thumbnails;

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];  

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"plist"];

        NSArray *tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        self.thumbnails = [NSMutableArray array];

          for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData){
             NSLog(@"%@",dict); // prints all key value pairs in dictionary
             [self.thumbnails addObject:dict[@"name"];
          }
          NSLog(@"outside %@", self.thumbnails);  // this prints last value added to thumbnails array 
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Initialize Cell

   cell.textLabel.text = self.thumbnails[indexPath.row];

   return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Anupdas, that created the right value for thumbnail within my viewDidLoad method but within the cellForRowAtIndexPath it is still empty :-(. I'm trying to declare this NSMutableArray thumbnails everywhere, in the header, in the implementation b/c I know it's creating one for just the viewDidLoad method and then using a different global one outside for the cellForRowAtIndexPath method but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: see end of my answer where I've edited a response for you. Thanks again!

Comment: @coreyData did you try my edit? If you are still uncertain show me the dataSource methods of tableView.

Comment: yes, I did, I have included my m file above. I will add .h file code shortly.

Comment: @coreyData In your viewDidLoad method you are not assigning the value of thumbnails to your property. Change thumbnails to self.thumbnails in that method. and in numberOfRowsInSection: method return [self.thumbnails count];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28786/discussion-between-anupdas-and-coreydata)

Answer (score 0):

There are several mishaps with your code.

A.  Looking at the provided plist data, you have an array of dictionaries.

B.  This line, allocated thumbnails as a local NSArray.

```
NSArray *thumbnails = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

But this line, what is self.thumbnails which is a property? It is not thumbnails above.  And it looks lie key @"name" contains an array rather than a final object.

```
self.thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: I replaced self.thumbnails with thumbnails but now in cellForRowAtIndexPath, thumbnails is an empty array. It no longer crashes though. Also in the plist name is the key for a string. Do I need to use allKeys somewhere in my code? Thanks for the guidance!